# Application.ThousandsSeparator only affects cells, chart labels, axis not working

Tags: excel, vba

I need some report where our clients can choose what thousand seperator they would like.

using below code this is working just fine for the cells. But the chart attached to it doesn't follow the same thousand seperator. Only when I save the file, close it and reopen it, the seperator is displayed correctly.

```
Sub changeSeperators()
    Application.ThousandsSeparator = " "
    Application.UseSystemSeparators = False
End Sub
```

I tried different Application. calculations, but none seem to work.
Also a refresh of the charts doesn't want to work.

If I don't do it within vba but just in the options of excel to change the seperator it is just working as supposed and updates both the cells as the chart labels, axes correctly

Any advice on how to tackle this?

Thanks,

Comment: Probably need to also explicitly change the numberformat code for the chart components.

Comment: Ron, even if I try to change the numberformat of the chart itself after the code, the format will still be the "old" one. Even though it's changed. Tried and tested a lot of things without success. Only thing thats working is to close the file and reopen